# Find if time is within range in format HH:MM-HH:MM

Tags: php, date, time

On my website, I have entries in the format `TITLE#HH:MM-HH:MM#LOCATION`. I can easily split this into 3 different array keys with `explode("#",...`, and display the data, but now I am working on creating a function to return whether the current timestamp is within the "HH:MM-HH:MM".

HH:MM-HH:MM is in the format of `12:20-13:10`, where the first time is the start time of the event, and the second time is when the event ends. I'm trying to detect whether the time the page loads and `time()` is called is within 12:20-13:10.

How would I go about doing this? I have tried creating some code but I'm not sure how to accomplish this cleanly.

Thanks!

***UPDATE*** --

```
        $tEvent = explode("-", $arr[1]);
        $now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time), new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));
        $start = new DateTime($tEvent[0], new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));
        $end = new DateTime($tEvent[1], new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));
        if ($now->format('U') >= $start->format('U') && $now->format('U') <= $end->format('U')) {
            //within time
        }
```

Comment: Even simply formatting the current time in the same format and then doing string comparison would work here …

Comment: How would I do that then? @Cbroe

Comment: Self-proclaimed “PHP developer” by your profile, and you need to ask that …? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You forgot the "and student." part.

Obviously I've looked at the date function, but I don't know how to compare strings containing both numbers and characters (such as "11:35"). 

No need to be so harsh. We all were students at one time, and we are always learning.

Comment: The digits in the strings will be compared like any other characters – and since `0` has the lowest code point and `9` the highest, you can do a simple `>=`/`<=` comparison on values in that format …

Comment: @Cbroe thank you!  I used some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with several different methods. Personally, I like to work with [`Datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to manipulate dates in php.

```
$timeEvent = "12:20-13:10"; // your string with start and end of the event
$tEvent = explode("-", $timeEvent); // split in 2 (0 is start, 1 is end)
$now = new Datetime("NOW"); // gets the actual date
$start = new Datetime($tEvent[0]); // create datetime object with start date
$end = new Datetime($tEvent[1]); // create datetime object with end date

if ( $now > $start && $now < $end ) // check if now is between start and end
{
    echo "It's event time!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, I used a combination of @1nflktd and @Cbroe code. One thing I would add to @1nflktd's code is that you need to use, for example, `if ( $now->format('U') > $start ...` instead of just `if ( $now > ...`